# Why is res.redirect not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently sending a GET request to my backend, when the user is seen as unauthenticated my goal is to redirect them to the sites login page, however when I try and redirect them, nothing happens and they remain on the same page. I have console logged the response and it is recieved by the front end but as I mentioned, the user isn't redirected.

Front end code:

```js
async function verify() {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
  };
  const verifyreq = await fetch('/user/verify', options);
  console.log(verifyreq);
}

window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.id == 'taskbar-user') {
    verify();
  }
});
```

Backend code:

```js
app.get('/user/verify', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    //do something
  } else {
    console.log('You have reached the else statement');
    res.redirect('/pages/login.html');
  }
});
```

I have made sure the user isn't authenticated and I have used console logging to make sure the `else` statement is reached. I have also put `redirect: 'follow'` into the options to no avail. So far no matter what I do, nothing happens. My current sollution is to just return a JSON that contains the authentication status and redirect the user depending on the value client side

Any help would be appreciated as I have been trying to sort this out for hours now, I'm sure it's probably a stupid mistake.

Comment: So what _does_ happen? Do you get into your `user/verify` function at all? Is the session accidentally already authenticated (in which case, that redirect never happens)? Does your code even make it into the `else`? Because if you've done all that (which you should mention in your post =) then you might see the redirect kicking in just fine, with the problem with `fetch`, and it might need `redirect: "follow"` in its options object.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have mentioned that in my post, however I have done everything you mentioned above, I've made sure the user isn't authenticated and used console logging to make sure my code makes it into the `else`. I've also tried using `redirect: 'follow'` to no avail. So far no matter what I do, nothing happens. My current sollution is to just return a JSON that contains the authentication status and redirect the user depending on the value client side.

Comment: Please put all that information [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), including showing your code with those console logs in it, and showing the backend console output you get when that fetch call happens.

Comment: It might be a bug indeed, although i'm not sure it comes from express. If someone could try it with another backend tech it would help to know if it's a browser or node/express bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` doesn't redirect by default, you need to implement the redirection

Here's a snippet I use, feel free to grab and use it

```
fetch.get = async (url) => {
    return fetch(url).then(data => {
        // Redirection happens here
        if (data.redirected) { return window.location.href = data.url; }
        return data.json();
    });
};

fetch.post = async (url, data = {}) => {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        redirect: 'follow',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(data => {
        // Redirection happens here
        if (data.redirected) { return window.location.href = data.url; }
        return data.json();
    });
};
```

Comment: Why would you do all of this instead of just adding [`redirect: "follow"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#redirect) to the options?

Comment: Good question, in some cases it doesn't seem to work (I didn't investigate this), while it might work on some browsers I had to implement the redirection as fallback

Comment: The only time it doesn't work is if you don't add it. With an explicit `redirect`, any time it doesn't work you're either not _actually_ getting a redirect (which uses the HTTP status 301, 302, or 307) such as someone sending a 200 with an HTML page that has a meta-refresh instruction instead to fake a redirect, or you found a browser bug that you should report.

Comment: _Doesn't_ it redirect by default? Per the spec, [_"Unless stated otherwise, it is `"follow"`. "_](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode)

Comment: `redirect: 'follow'` is the default, but "redirect" means "get what you asked from this URL instead"; it doesn't mean "navigate the main browser viewport to this URL". The redirect is followed, then the promise returned by `fetch` is resolved, then you can use `then()` to access the response and get the data from the response.

Comment: Feel free to try it yourself, Brave on Linux (ubuntu + xfce4 DE) with latest stack node/express server.